# is there a way to recuperate a directory erased with svn rm after add but before commit?

Tags: svn, latex, osx-snow-leopard

I stupidly did an svn rm --force to a directory that had just been added, but not committed, thinking that it would erase the "add" but not the local copy. Is there any way I can recuperate the content of the directory?

BTW the file was a .tex file and I was working with Texshop at the time..just in case it gives ideas...

Tks.

Comment: Is **TimeMachine** running on your system?

Answer (score 0):

Following the svn documentation ...

> Add files and directories to your
>   working copy and schedule them for
>   addition to the repository. They will
>   be uploaded and added to the
>   repository on your next commit. If you
>   add something and change your mind
>   before committing, you can unschedule
>   the addition using svn revert.

*svn add* does not upload your files to the repository. Therefore you must rely on recovery tools provided by your operating system. On OS X 'Snow Leopard' with  'TimeMachine' running you might be able to recover your files.